# Shell script cut the beginning and the end of a file

Tags: file, shell, sed, cut

So I have a file and I'd like cut the first 33 lines and the last 6 lines of it. What I am trying to do is get the whole file in a cat command (cat file) and then use the "head" and "tail" commands to remove those parts, but I don't know how to do so.
Eg (this is just the idea)

```
cat file - head -n 33 file - tail -n 6 file
```

How am I supposed to do this? Is it possible to do it with "sed" (how)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can delete the first 33 lines with `sed` easily enough: `sed '1,33d' file`.  What `sed` can't do is count backwards from the last line (or the current line), so the 'last 6 lines' part is not sensibly solvable with `sed`.  (There are extraordinary gyrations you can go through with the hold space and the pattern space, but it is better for your sanity not to explore them.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it has already been answered with `sed`, without using the hold space. However, I get your point.

Comment: @StevenPenny: I hadn't done the `sed` script mentally, and yes, there's a solution that works for the case of 33 and 6 with just the pattern space (so I over-complicated it).  However, generalizing that solution to handle 25 and 20 would be a messy exercise in `sed`-script generation, and to handle 200 and 250 does not bear thinking about.  From that point of view, using `tail` to get all but the first N lines and `head` to get all but the last M lines is better (at least you only have to adjust one integer value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
$ tail -n +34 file | head -n -6
```

See the `tail`

> -n, --lines=K
>                 output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth

and `head`

> -n, --lines=[-]K
>                 print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file

man pages.

Example:

```
$ cat file
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight

$ tail -n +4 file | head -n -2
four
five
six
```

Notice that you don't need the `cat` (see [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)).

Answer (score 2):

first count total lines, then print the middle part: **(read file twice)**

```
l=$(wc -l file)
awk -v l="$l" 'NR>33&&NR<l-6' file
```

or load the file in array, then print lines you need : **(read file once)**

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=34;i<NR-6;i++)print a[i]}' file
```

or awk with head,  don't think so much in this way: **(read file twice)**:

```
awk 'NR>33' file|head -n-6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -n '1,33b; 34{N;N;N;N;N};N;P;D' file
```

this will work +

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1,33d;:a;$d;N;s/\n/&/6;Ta;P;D' file
```